# Copying the newest files

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, timestamps

We have a script running which picks up the report generated monthly on remote servers.  I was trying to find a way to pick up the latest file from the remote servers only.  Will find work in script or that's a bad practice?

```
for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    scp "$host":"$remote_path" "$local_target_dir"/filename."$host"
done
```

File format =  servername_BBC-3.0_2014-06-04_164510_.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can run a `ls -rt` via SSH on the server within the directory to find out the last modified file (based on its last modification date instead of the filename)

```
fileToCopy=$(ssh "$host" "cd $remote_path && ls -rt | tail -1")
scp "$host":"$remote_path"/"$fileToCopy" "$local_target_dir"/filename."$host"
```

Comment: surely you meant command substitution at `fileToCopy='ssh "$host$" "cd $remote_path" && ls -rt | tail -1"'` ?

Comment: I meant store the name of the file inside the variable `fileToCopy` and then use the filename in the script given in the question.

Comment: Chirag, understood. But you are attempting to run ssh within single quotes, you must have meant back-quotes?

Comment: @1_CR: You're right. I tested the code in parts using double quotes, but forgot that it wouldn't work in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to find it out validating your date and have in consideration the last backup, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
day=${date +%d}
last_month=${date -d "-1 month" date +%Y-%m-%d}
if [ $day -eq 15]
then
    echo "Is 15th, time to make get last backup!"
    scp -P port user@server:/dir/servername_BBC-3.0_$last_month* destination
fi
```